# How to disable PyDev console debugger in PyCharm when not debugging?

Tags: pycharm

Whenever I run a script in PyCharm, it starts the PyDev debugger (with IPython terminal).

- My script does not fail or raise any errors, and
- I'm not debugging: I'm running **"Run"** -> **"Run file.py"** from menu.

I've figured out how to disable the *IPython* terminal, but then it just runs the "normal" terminal instead. I just want to run scripts and print output to console, and then exit.

How to disable this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution was to go to **Run**->**Edit Configurations...** and for the run configuration *untick* the box that says **Show command line afterwards** (See image below.)

If you have any existing run configurations, they must all be changed. Changing the default configuration will, as expected, affect all new configurations. A configuration is created for each file that is being run.

**Update:** Thanks to @smb for adding that for Mac users or people on Py Charm Professional 2018.1.1: the Show command line afterwards option is now called "Run with Python Console". Unticking this box has the same effect as the "Show command line afterwards" option.

[image]

Comment: Just an update that Mac Users/ people on Py Charm Professional 2018.1.1 the Show command line afterwards option is now called "Run with Python Console". Unticking this box has the same effect as the "Show command line afterwards" option.